# Not able to access ropsten account

Tags: truffle, ether, metamask, ropsten

I installed ropsten testnet and created 2 accounts. "eth.accounts" returns the following:

```
["0x54eb2b021a26c17b83927ad14587a24b0bd16b66", "0x14e6b19304fb3c98a73acea5f80d2c056ee5c09f"]
```

I wanted to import these accounts using Metamask and get some test ether. I uploaded the latest file from `"/home/vivek/.ethereum/testnet/keystore"`. After importing when I copied the account address using metamask the account address copied to clipboard was :

```
"0x58708227265c1e38417D9B3AEf8FfCFb4Be9AE50"
```

The above account is none of the accounts from the "eth.accounts" command. But the address mentioned in the json file I imported is "`14e6b19304fb3c98a73acea5f80d2c056ee5c09f`"